# Would this M.SE question that has received no answers be appropriate for MO? (or could it be tweaked into being appropriate?)

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667830/modern-research-into-grassmans-theory-of-forms

When I first posted it on MO, it received a downvote, so I figured there might be something wrong with it and just deleted it.

I haven't gotten an answer on M.SE even after putting up a bounty on it though (and the bounty has almost run out...). I'm very keen on getting some sort of a definitive answer!

Is it possible to improve this question somehow to have it fit on MO, or does it just not belong here in any stretch of the imagination?

Comment: I think that arsmath's comment on your question is as good an answer as you're going to get.  I don't think this question is appropriate for MathOverflow.  In general, given your background as described in the comments on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663823/suggestions-for-a-learning-roadmap-for-universal-algebra (i.e. an engineering student who doesn't know much pure math), I really don't think that you're going to be able to fruitfully use MathOverflow (as your numerous closed [and since deleted] questions demonstrate).

Comment: @AndyPutman Thanks! I will remember to go away forever.

Comment: +1, thanks for asking, even though the answer was "no".